# How can I immitate a for loop with ng-repeat angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display a list inside a list. This loop works in JavaScript.

```
for ( i=0; self.InsuredCommoditiesList.length > i; i++){
       self.CommoditiesCategories = self.InsuredCommoditiesList[i].Category;
           for (j = 0; self.InsuredCommoditiesList[i].Items.length > j; j++) {
                        self.CommoditiesList = self.InsuredCommoditiesList[i].Items[j]; 
                    }
```

This is the body of my ng-repeat

```
<label ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
        {{commo.Category}}
       <input type="checkbox"> {{commo.Items}}
</label>
```

And my result is almost correct, the problem is that **"Items"** are not being display individually. Instead it's just showing the whole array.

Example in the following picture:
[image]

Can I use something similar to position **"j"** in my *ng-repeat* to display the items individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in each list can be displayed using a list, for example: an [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) (i.e. `<ul>`) or an [ordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) (i.e. `<ol>`), with a [list item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) (i.e. `<li>`) for each item in the array. In the example below, `item` is analogous to `self.InsuredCommoditiesList[i].Items[j]` in the for loop of the regular JavaScript example.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in commo.Items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

In fact, there is a *repeat_expression*<sup>1</sup> where `j` could be used in a similar manner: `(key, value) in expression`, which would look like below:

```
<li ng-repeat="(j,item) in commo.Items">{{item}}</li>
```

A `<label>` is only permitted to only contain [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)</sup> but the lists are [Flow Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) so move the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) up to another parent element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`. Then make the label, input and list tags child elements.

```
<div ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
    <label for="checkbox_{{$index}}">{{commo.Category}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{$index}}">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in commo.Items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See a demonstration of this below.

```js
angular.module('QQapp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    this.InsuredCommoditiesList = [{
        "id": 3,
        "Category": "Agricultural liquids - Petroleum",
        "Items": ["100% Produce", "Alcohol", "Appliances"]
      },
      {
      "id": 4,
        "Category": "Grocery Items (dry)",
        "Items": ["Candy", "Canned goods", "Containers"]
      },
      {
      "id": 6,
        "Category": "Building materials",
        "Items": ["Alfalfa", "All Non-perishable General Merchandise", "Almonds"]
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="QQapp" ng-controller="ctrl as QQCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
    <label for="checkbox_{{$index}}">{{commo.Category}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{$index}}">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(j,item) in commo.Items" id="{{commo.id}}_{{j}}" >{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> refer to the **Arguments** section of [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for supported formats

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the inner loop of your equivalent javascript code in angularjs as well, i.e. you will need one more `ng-repeat`.

Something like:

```
<label ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
        {{commo.Category}}
       <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in commo.Items"> {{item}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two loops in your JavaScript code, so you will need two loops in the angular to go through the inner list.

```
    <label ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
            {{commo.Category}}
           <input type="checkbox"> 
           <label ng-repeat="item in commo.Items" >{{item}}</label>
    </label>
```

Untested, but should work assuming commo.Items is a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

```
<label ng-repeat="commo in QQCtrl.InsuredCommoditiesList track by $index">
        {{commo[0].Category}}
       <input type="checkbox"> {{commo[0].Items}}
</label>
```